# How to get the id out of the get_categories objects

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to display the id's of my categories using the **get_categories** function.

I have looked on google and stackexchange and foud these 2 methods

```
$categories = get_categories( 
    array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ) 
);

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<p>' .'Category id'. $category->cat_id . '</p>';
    // the method above and below are the ones i found
    // but both the id and cat_id give no results
    echo '<p>' .'Category id'. $category->id . '</p>';
```

}

I know i can use:

```
echo get_cat_ID( $category->name );
```

But i want i want it clean like the code above.

Anyone has any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: first print $categories, and lets check weather it is getting cat_id or id keys in the array, if the id is getting in array, then call the exact key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that "cat_ID" is a pseudonym of "term_id" and can only be used with a limited set of functions. You mention get_cat_ID and its [source shows it returns term_id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_cat_id/#source).

Your existing code may work if you change *cat_id* to ***cat_ID*** -  but I'd use ***term_id*** instead (it certainly works for me with the "similar" get_the_category function)